# Integration problem on multiple variables

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I would like to ask help on this integration problem:
$$\int_0^1\int_0^1\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\;\left[1-\alpha(1-2x)(1-2y)\right]dxdy$$
I was wondering if polar substitution is possible. I have done the substitution $r^2=x^2+y^2$; however, I do not know then how to proceed. I hope someone can help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the polar substitution, $x=r\cos \theta, y=r\sin \theta$. So the integrand will be written as follows:

$$
\sqrt{x^2+y^2}[1-a(1-2x)(1-2y)]\to r\left(1-a(1-2r\cos \theta)(1-2r\sin \theta)\right)
$$ which is:
$$f(r,\theta)=r-ar+2\sqrt{2}ar^2\sin\left(\theta+\frac{\pi}4\right)-2ar^3\sin(2\theta)$$ According to the below plot:

[image]

we have:

$$\left(\int_0^{\pi/4}\int_0^{\sec(\theta)}+\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}\int_0^{\csc(\theta)}\right)f(r,\theta)rdrd\theta$$

Comment: I think you meant $-2ar^3\text{sin}(2\theta)$ as the last term of $f(r,\theta)$?

Comment: @math_stat_enthusiast: Yes. sorry. I was typing expanding and collecting at the same time.

Comment: Ok. Thanks :) Although I am still wondering about how the limits of integration were obtained.

Comment: Will it be ok if you explain how the limits of the integration were obtained? I am really having a hard time understanding why. Thanks.

Comment: @math_stat_enthusiast: That is OK my friend. You have a region $0\leq x\leq 1,~~0\leq y\leq 1$. I made it apart into two right angled color triangulars. in the Brown one the $\theta$ is changing from $0$ to $\pi/4$ while $r=0$ to $1=r\cos(\theta)$. Can you find them for the Purple one?

Comment: Ok. So for the purple one it is $r=0$ to $1=r\text{sin}(\theta)$. Wow! That was creative of you to take it into two parts. Thanks :)

Comment: @math_stat_enthusiast: Welcome my friend ;-)

Comment: @amWhy: Thanks dear friend. :-)